# Best practice with models inside services in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, model, controller

I am developing a web application using AngularJS. I have several controllers in the same view that render different presentations of some central data. One of the views is textual, another is a table and a third is a graph.

Reading up on how this could be implemented in the most elegant way with AngularJS I centralized my model in a service, which via a getter allows controllers to get a reference to the model. Using this approach, when anything changes in that central model, the views update themselves beautifully with the internal magic of AngularJS as the model is exposed to the scope on each controller.

But I have received a couple of comments from other developers that this approach is not good practice. They suggest that the controller should only provide copies of the model to the controllers and that it should populate an event if the model changes so that the controllers ask for a new copy of the updated model. To me personally this feels like adding complexity to an implementation and reinventing the wheel on top of AngularJS for something AngularJS manages to handle automatically for me with its own dirty checking.

Are references to a model in a service really bad practice? If so, why?

In my eyes the suggested event idea is quite bad practice as it forces me to broadcast events on $rootScope as services do not have their own scope. Trying this idea results in an application where the view updates are visibly much slower and where AngularJS has to do quite more to achieve the same results (broadcast the event, add event handlers in each controller, creating and returning multiple copies of the same model, setting these different copies in each controller scope so that AngularJS only then reacts on dirty checking).

It would be interesting to see what you guys here feel about subject.

Happy New Year to you all!

Answer (score 0):

Services should return the result of your query, like:

```
function getData() {
    return $http.get("/user/123");
}
```

Controllers should use that data:

```
$scope.userInfo = [];

yourService.getData().then(function (result) {
    $scope.userInfo = result.data;
}
```

You wrote:

> They suggest that the controller should only provide copies of the model to the controllers and that it should populate an event if the model changes so that the controllers ask for a new copy of the updated model.

I don't know if it counts as a bad practice, I wouldn't do it this way, that's for sure. As you've mentioned, Angular already manages the events that fire off when the model changes, so I agree with you that it would be an extra unnecessary thing to do, but I might be proven wrong.

Here are some good guidelines, maybe you could use them in your project: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide